# Keyboard closes directly after opening in an extended FormField

Tags: flutter, key, form-fields

When building a custom form field by extending `FormField` (with a `TextFormField` centered within two `IconButton`s), I encounter unexpected issues with the keyboard.

After a state change due to a button press, the `TextFormField` is only updated when it has been provided with a key during construction (e.g. `UniqueKey()`). However, when using keys in this way, the keyboard directly closes after opening. The keyboard only works properly when no key is provided to `TextFormField`. When the key from the `FormField` baseclass constructor is provided, the keyboard also doesn't work and `TextFormField` is not updated when an `IconButton` is pressed.

When using the iOS simulator, no error is received when the keyboard closes directly after opening. When using a physical device, I get the following error:

```
Successfully load keyboard extensions
[lifecycle] [u 4EF1D37A-3BC9-4488-BC5A-A32FFFD4094F:m (null)] [com.google.keyboard.KeyboardExtension(2.3.19)] RB query for the extension process state failed with error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "Client not entitled" UserInfo={RBSEntitlement=com.apple.runningboard.process-state, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Client not entitled, RBSPermanent=false}
```

The problem occurs at various versions of flutter, among which is version `3.7.0-1.3.pre`.

Is this a bug or should the keys be used in another way?

Code that illustrates the problem

```
class CustomNumberFormField extends FormField<double> {
  final int scale;
  final TextStyle? textStyle;

  CustomNumberFormField({
    required FormFieldSetter<double> onSaved,
    this.scale = 0,
    this.textStyle,
    super.validator,
    super.key,
    super.initialValue,
  }) : super(
          onSaved: onSaved,
          builder: (FormFieldState<double> state) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                      onPressed: () {
                        state.didChange((state.value != null)
                            ? state.value! - 1
                            : initialValue);
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 100,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        ///////////////////////////
                        // Problem occurs here:
                        key: UniqueKey(), // key: key,
                        // Keyboard cannot be used when the above keys are used (i.e. UniqueKey() or from baseclass). 
                        // However, state changes due to pressing IconButton do not update text value without using UniqueKey(). 
                        // Using the baseclass key also results in closing the keyboard and IconButtons do not update  TextFormField
                        initialValue: NumberFormat("#.#").format(state.value),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                            decimal: (scale > 0)),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(
                              scale > 0 ? r'[0-9]+[,.]{0,1}[0-9]*' : r'[0-9]')),
                          TextInputFormatter.withFunction(
                            (oldValue, newValue) => newValue.copyWith(
                              text: newValue.text.replaceAll('.', ','),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                        style: textStyle,
                        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                        onSaved: (value) {
                          if (value != null && value != "") {
                            NumberFormat().parse(value).toDouble();
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                      onPressed: () {
                        state.didChange((state.value != null)
                            ? state.value! + 1
                            : initialValue);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                state.hasError
                    ? Text(
                        state.errorText ?? "",
                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                      )
                    : Container()
              ],
            );
          },
        );
}
```

Comment: I haven't played around with keys yet, but my assumption is that a new unique key is generated everytime. Did you use `CustomNumberFormField(key: const UniqueKey())`? If that isn't valid code, maybe try saving it in a variable during initState(). e.g. `fieldKey = UniqueKey()` and then use `fieldKey` during build()

Comment: UniqueKey() cannot be created with a const constructor. When a key is created in `initState()`, the keyboard works but the buttons do not (which is similar behavior when using the `super.key`). So odd...